# How to avoid flake8's "F821 undefined name '_'" when _ has been installed by gettext?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gettext, pyflakes, flake8

### Problem overview:

In my project's main script, `gettext` installs the function `_()` that is used in other modules for translations (like in `print(_('Something to translate'))`).

As stated by [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gettext.install):

> the _() function [is] installed in Python’s builtins namespace, so it is easily accessible in all modules of your application.

So, everything runs fine.

*Only problem*: `flake8` shows errors (actually returned by PyFlakes):

```
$ flake8 *.py
lib.py:2:12: F821 undefined name '_'
main_script.py:8:7: F821 undefined name '_'
```

This is normal, as `_` is indeed not defined in main_script.py nor lib.py.

### Simple structure that reproduces the problem:

```
.
├── lib.py
├── locale
│   └── de
│       └── LC_MESSAGES
│           ├── myapp.mo
│           └── myapp.po
└── main_script.py
```

Where lib.py contains this:

```
def fct(sentence):
    return _(sentence)
```

and main_script.py this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gettext

import lib

gettext.translation('myapp', 'locale', ['de']).install()
print(_('A sentence'))
print(lib.fct('A sentence'))
```

and myapp.po contains:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: myapp\n"

msgid "A sentence"
msgstr "Ein Satz"
```

(was compiled by poedit to produce the mo file).

As stated above, the main script does work:

```
$ ./main_script.py 
Ein Satz
Ein Satz
```

**Important note: I'm looking for a solution working both for the script where `gettext.install()` is called *and* all other modules that *do not need to call* `gettext.install()`.** Otherwise, the structure could be even more simple, because calling `_()` from main_script.py is enough to trigger F821.

### Solutions to solve the situation that look bad (or worse):

- add a `# noqa` comment at the end of each line using `_()`
- `--ignore` F821 (don't want to do that because this is useful in other situations)

Comment: If you don't mind arguments, you can specify `--builtins="_"` which is more specific than `--ignore F821`.

Comment: Well, yes this solves the problem efficiently. You could post this as an answer.

Comment: Classic well researched question, getting a concise and effective answer (which was directly relevant to my needs).

Comment: @BobHy I must precise that after having experienced weird issues at other places (pytest and doctests), directly caused by this use of `_` as a translation shortcut, I finally decided to abandon this. I replaced `_` by `tr` and import it anytime necessary as I do for any other module.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could specify the `--builtins="_"` which is more specific than `--ignore F821`.

You should be able to specify this in a configuration file as well if you don't like command line arguments.

Comment: Many thanks for this precision about the configuration file! For atom linter-flake8 plugin, there's no setting yet, but it's indeed possible to add the line `builtins = _` in the flake8 config file used for the project (what overrides the settings defined in atom).

Comment: I must precise that after having experienced weird issues at other places (pytest and doctests), directly caused by this use of `_` as a translation shortcut, I finally decided to abandon this. I replaced `_` by `tr` and import it anytime necessary as I do for any other module.