# pyflakes say "'_' may be undefined" when using gettext class-based API

Tags: python, gettext, pyflakes

I do use [GNU gettext class-based API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#localizing-your-application). In practice this means that the function `_()` is not explicit declare by myself in each module like this:

```
import gettext
t = gettext.translation('spam', '/usr/share/locale')
_ = t.gettext
```

But it is done like this

```
import gettext
gettext.install('myapplication')
```

In the back this `install()` declares the `_()` in the back and place it into the builtins namespace so I can use it in every module.

But this is a problem from the point of view of linters like pyflake:

```
pyflakes: '_' may be undefined, or defined from star imports
```

Of course I do use `_()` everywhere in my code but it is not declare elsewhere but implicit via `gettext.install()`.

Any idea how to solve this? There are a lot of locations where I do use `_()`. So I don't want to put an `# noqa` behind it.

Comment: Bad design on the part of `gettext` IMO, in multiple respects.  You could maybe wrap it in something that defines a default value for `_` at import time (like a function that just raises an exception).

Comment: Some hints and maybe a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840142/how-to-avoid-flake8s-f821-undefined-name-when-has-been-installed-by-get